# MongoDB - Mongoose , Adding new document data in nested query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I couldn't push the data in the nested query

I couldn't understand what I missed in my code (I am new in mongodb just experimenting )

**My target is adding 'post' in posts**

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const UserDetail = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    email: String,
    posts: {
        post:{
            title: String,
            article: String,
            comments: {}
        }
    }
});
const User = mongoose.model('userInfo', UserDetail, 'userInfo');

module.exports = User;
```

Here my updating code

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.user._id},{ $push: {"posts": { "post" : { "article": req.body.description }} }     });
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push)** is used to append a specified value to an array. If the field is absent in the document to update, it adds the array field with the value as its element but if the field is not an array, the operation will fail. In your case `posts` is an embedded document, not an array.

You can either update your schema to make `posts` an array as:

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const UserDetail = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    email: String,
    posts: [
        {
            title: String,
            article: String,
            comments: []
        }
    ]
})
```

then do a push

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user,
   { "$push": { 
       "posts": { 
           "article": req.body.description  
       } 
   } }  
);
```

---

or use **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation)** with the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) if using the existing schema. The operation with **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation)** follows this example:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user,
   { "set": { "posts.post.article": req.body.description  } } 
);
```